# vserver phpmyadmin error on every password change

Tags: mysql, linux, database, phpmyadmin

I installed Phpmyadmin and MySQL with apache2 to my Vserver, but Im getting on Every Password change this error

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

and this

```
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

what is here the Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phpMyAdmin application has a set of additional features that can be enabled by creating an additional user (called the controluser); those features include things like bookmarking queries and saving a log of queries run.

The error message you're getting indicates that the controluser has been configured in the configuration file `config.inc.php`, but the user account doesn't actually exist.

The simple solution here is to remove the lines from `config.inc.php`. You probably have two lines, like these:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']
```

You can remove those lines or comment them out. Save the file and try accessing phpMyAdmin again.